# Can I add a customized button in the ionic popup window body

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, popup

I have created a ionic popup window, instead of the default two buttons at the bottom, I would like to add a button in the body of the popup window. Actually does it really possible to do so? If not, another other method / suggestion?

I have tried to insert some html code in the template but it didn't work.
I would like to add a button like the grey button as shown in the diagram. Thank you for your time for reading my question.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add a customized button to the body of an ionic popup by injecting it into the template. Below is based off of Ionics Popup nightly build with no logic.

Please visit the codepen at the bottom so you can see it in action. If you want to customize the popup, as well, you can apply a custom css class to it too.

```
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PopupCtrl',function($scope, $ionicPopup) {

// Triggered on a button click, or some other target
$scope.showPopup = function() {
$scope.data = {}

var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
 title: 'Title',
 template: '<p>Customer Detail</p> <button type="button">Print</button>',
 scope: $scope,
 cssClass:'customPopupClass',
 buttons: [
     {text: 'Back' },
     {text: '<b>Submit</b>', type: 'button-dark',},
    ]
   });
  };
});
```

cssClass example to customize popup even more:

```
   .customPopupClass{
      .popup{
        //style for popup
      }
      .popup-title{
        //style for title
      }
    }
```

List of CSS classes to override and customize popup even further

- .popup
- .popup-head
- .popup-title
- .popup-sub-title
- .popup-body
- .popup-buttons.row
- .popup-buttons .button

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOoOgd) so you can play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

If by create you mean you actually created/designed this dialog box you can customize it any way you like. You can use http://jqueryui.com/dialog/.

You can use these libraries to create HTML elements that look and behave like a dialog box/popup window, allowing you to put anything you want (including buttons) in the dialog.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. It is my mistake that I did not make it clear that I am now using the ionic popup window... seems the jquery dialog box is not applicable on it. Anyway, thanks for your sharing!